# can 3D diffusion be interpreted as superposition of 1D diffusion

Tags: diffusion

Is diffusion of a substance in water independent in the X, Y and Z directions? In other words, if I want to solve how a substance diffuses through a volume, can I separately solve equations for its diffusion in the X direction, the Y direction and the Z direction, and then sum them together to get the total diffusion?

Comment: Is it a linear process? Or a nonlinear process?

Comment: Or perhaps another way to look at it... write down your equation. What does the equation do? Are there mixed spatial derivatives?

Comment: In general I don't think this will work. Imagine you have a cylinder filled with water. The dependence of the temperature with respect to the radial direction involves Bessel functions, something you'll never be able to yield with a one dimensional problem I believe.